# Extract JSON strings from text file where JSON strings are not separated by comma

Tags: java, json

I have a text file containing JSON objects without separated by comma, like following,

```
{"fieldA":"value A", "fieldB":"value B"}

{"fieldA":"valueA_", "fieldB":"valueB_", "fieldC":"valueC"}

{"fieldA":"valueA_", "fieldB":"valueB__", "fieldC":"valueC_"}
```

Now, I have to create a list/array of JSON objects using Java. Above are just sample JSON, actual JSON are big, that's why I can not do line by line reading.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have attempted so far?

Comment: Are you using any Json Parser library?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over items and iterate as one object per line and process them.

Add lines (Strings) dynamically to a list if you don't know the size.

```
List<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>(); // create a new list
String line = in.readLine(); // read a line at a time
while(line != null){ // loop till you have no more lines
    lines.add(line) // add the line to your list
    line = in.readLine(); // try to read another line
}

// Process lines here or in loop above
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally,

Please not that every json object starts with the same field(i.e. fieldA in above example). I replaced {"fieldA": with ,{"fieldA": (added comma between two consecutive json strings)in the whole string and took the substring between first and last(including) character. Then, I added [ in the starting and ] in the end to construct the array of json string. I used Jackson library for mapping and created the array of json objects.